# Is it true that intransitive verbs cannot be used in passive?

Tags: grammar

Do this grammar rule include all of intransitive verbs? If yes, so in this sense, can't I say

> this has been tried several times

it sounds pretty ok to me.

Comment: I have tried this several times. "This" is used as the object. What have u trued? This.

Answer (score 2):

The change from passive to active voice works like this:

> subject verb object - active voice
>
> object verb - passive voice

An intransitive verb, by definition, does not have an object, so you cannot form a passive voice version from an intransitive verb.

Many verbs can be used both transitively or intransitively: sometimes the meaning is different. For example

> I see you - transitive - means that I can perceive you with my eyes
>
> I see - intransitive - means that I understand.

[try](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/try) can be transitive or intransitive - note that it says I or T in the defintion that I quoted.

Here is a possible active voice version of your sentence:

> We have tried **this** several times

Note that **this** is the object of the verb **try** so we are using a transitive form: it is therefore possible to form a passive voice version.